# DirectX DLL won't install

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, dll, regsvr32

I'm trying to play Heroes of Might and Magic V on Windows 7. I'm missing a d3dx9_25.dll. I  downloaded the dll, and copied this to C:/Windows/System32 (which I believe is the folder for 64-bit, but I wasn't sure so I also copied the same dll in C:Windows/SysWOW64). I run the regsvr32.exe, but I get error message:

The module "d3dx9_25.dll" may not compatible with the version of Windows that you're running. Check if the module is compatible with an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe.

How do I check the compatibility, and more importantly, how do I make it work properly? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of downloading single DLLs from probably dubious sources, you should just install DirectX 9. You can get it on http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35.

Comment: Okay.. I've now come across a different problem. Error message says "Extracting file failed. It is most likely caused by low memory (low disk space for swapping file) or corrupted Cabinet file". :(

Comment: Since you accepted my answer I guess you solved the new problem yourself, probably by downloading the file again. Is this correct?